# Select related feature among layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, relates

Is it possible in ArcGIS 10.x that if I select a feature in one layer it will also select the related feature in another layer?

Answer (score 5):

Not automatically, but you can set up related tables, and from the Attribute Table you select Related Tables and it'll open the related table and select the matching records.

**Establish your Relate** from Layer Properties > Joins & Relates tab (this only needs to be done once per Relate):
[image]

**Select a Feature** from one of the Layers:
[image]

From the Attribute Table menu select **Related Tables > *name of your Relate***
[image]

This will open the table of the other layer, with **Related features selected**
[image]